# Rails: Complex polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model who has one Profession (Designer, Model, Photograph, ...). Each profession has specific attributes, so each profession has its own table.

Now in my User I would like to say that a User has_one :profession, where the profession is Photograph, Designer, or whatever else.

My first idea was to use the Profession model as a STI but if I do this I cannot have a table for each real profession...

How would you design this?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would flip the `has_one` association to a `belongs_to` and use polymorphic associations.  The model code would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profession, :polymorphic => true
end


# similar code for other professions
class Designer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profession
end
```

Migration would look like this:

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.references :profession, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: I thought about that but it feels weird to flip the associations. But it is a workable solution

Comment: In a one-to-one relationship, `belongs_to` and `has_many` are semantically used depending on which table holds the foreign 'id' of the other.  It doesn't really have to have any meaning beyond that.

Comment: This works, assuming that each entry in the designers table is unique to every user.  If you wanted to have entries that could map to any number of users, then this would not work.  Nice solution though.

Comment: @SeanHill, I assume that it is unique per user, or there wouldn't have been a requirement for a separate table for each type.

Comment: Yeah, it is unclear, but you could have in the designers table entries like, fashion designer, graphic designer, graphic designer II, etc.  In that case, I would want those to be shared across multiple users.

Comment: Alright, well there you go... straight from the horse's mouth.  As I said before, nice solution.  Cheers!